# What extra things does the uTorrent installation do if use the default settings?

Tags: installation, utorrent

I installed uTorrent half asleep on my new computer and forget to unclick the "optional" install features, does anyone know what exactly did to my computer ?

I already had uninstalled Avast and restored my default search engine, I'm just wondering if it did install any other bloatware or messed with some configuration other than the seach engine?

Comment: Just uninstall it completely and reinstall it again with “optional” unchecked.

Comment: @JakeGould I'm pretty sure that wouldn't uninstall Avast or restore my messed up browser, thats the problem I'm trying to revert anything it might have messed up.

Comment: Where did you download utorrent from?

Comment: @Moab https://www.utorrent.com/